# Using Maven's .m2/settings.xml throws warning in Eclipse m2e

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, eclipse-juno, m2e

I'm using Maven's settings.xml to override a property value for a log4j.properties file for development purposes.  However, after I made this change, I now receive warnings in Eclipse m2e even though this is a normal use case:

> Access "/Users/junger/.m2" directory outside of project base
>   directory.
>   (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources:default-resources:process-resources)

How do I remove this warning?  Or, is there a bug tracking this?  I couldn't find one.

In my pom.xml, I have -

```
<properties>
    <log4j.properties.directory>src/main/java</log4j.properties.directory>
</properties>
```

In my settings.xml, I have -

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <log4j.properties.directory>/Users/junger/.m2/</log4j.properties.directory>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Could you show us the relevant part of your pom.xml?

Comment: @chkal, Yes, I added pom.xml and settings.xml to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.core/src/org/eclipse/m2e/core/internal/builder/EclipseBuildContext.java) (the `newScanner()` method) of m2e, this seems to be an explicit warning when your project references files outside of its base directory.

For me, this warning is kind of justified. When you are referencing resources outside of your project's basedir, your builds might not be reproducible anymore. Your projects should rather be self contained without depending on external files.